# Angular dropdown list has an empty line above options

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-directive

I have a dropdown menu with three categories.

```
<select ng-model="model.RegionId">
   <option value="">---Please Select a Region---</option>
   <option value="1" ng-selected="model.RegionId == '1'">US</option>
   <option value="2" ng-selected="model.RegionId == '2'">Europe</option>
   <option value="3" ng-selected="model.RegionId == '3'">APAC</option>
</select>
```

If the value of `model.Region` is set to one of the regions (in the database or from the UI), and then next time when I open the dropdown menu, I see an empty line above all options.

[image]

I guess it's related to some init problem but I am really new to Angular and don't have much clue. Can anyone help me remove that empty line as shown in the pic? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yeah the way to reproduce it is (1) On the UI, select one of the region, for example `Europe`, click `Save` then this selected value will be stored in the backend database; (2) Close this page; (3) Open this page and you will see `Europe` selected. But then if you open this drop-down menu again to change for another region, the empty line will show up there.

Comment: Tried setting a value to `model.RegionId` directedly in app.controller and the issue couldn't be re-produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let make an object of your options like

```
 $scope.model = {};
    $scope.model.RegionId = "1";

    $scope.model.countries = [{
      id: "1",
      name: "USA"
    }, {
      id: "2",
      name: "Europe"
    }, {
      id: "3",
      name: "APAC"
    }];
  });
```

and in html

```
<div>
     Targeted Region :
      <select ng-model="model.RegionId" ng-options="country.id as country.name for country in model.countries">
        <option value="">-- please choose Targeted Region --</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
     Targeted-Id : {{model.RegionId}}
    </div>
```

in such a way you can able to whenever the model value is set it will be checked and if not then please **choose Targeted Region** will be shown.

also, don't forget to assign a value from API to ng-model

Comment: Thanks for the input @Hrishikesh This fixed my problem but I don't know what you mean by `assign a value from API to ng-model`. Can you give me an example?

Comment: In the case where you want to show the user selected value So when ever you are getting a value from api like which is selected . Or any just assign that value to your $scope.model.RegionId. So by default whichever the id is it will be selected.